# Breaking down a video mp4 to cuts like a video editor?

Tags: video

If I'm given a video, what API should I use to cut the video to understand the underlaying tactics the video editor used like cuts, copy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for might be something similar to per frame metadata - i.e. metadata related to a particular clip or section of the video, rather than the whole video.

This would allow you examine metadata associated with different edits etc and search for keywords.

MP4 and similar video containers do not usually contain per frame metadata AFAIK, but you may find support in other formats used in video post production like DPX (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Picture_Exchange).

It may be that your requirement could be met by adding the comments of data you need in a separate text track, similar to subtitles.